# Moving data from a Drupal 6 site to a new Drupal 7 site

Tags: migrations

This is not an drupal 6 to 7 upgrade question, at least not in the way it's conventionally asked or done. I have an ill pressflow 6.17 site with loads of not necessary modules, configurations, etc, which I need to convert to Drupal 7 (Pressflow 7 doesn't seem to be round the corner as work on Drupal 8 has just started) so this will be a new site with its own set of modules and configurations but with the same data as the old site. I don't want anything from the Pressflow site to creep into the Drupal 7 site except for content; I don't want the views, imagecache presets, etc. I am looking to get advice on just moving the data (content) from Pressflow to Drupal 7 site; therefore, the usual upgrade process will not work for me.

I have used the migrate module before for an ASP to Drupal migration and it works great, but it's also kind of messy with source tables residing in the same database, and since task at hand is to move data from one Drupal version to another I am hoping for a much simpler/quicker technique.

What would be the best/quickest way to move content and only content (including ratings, comments) from Drupal/Pressflow 6 to Drupal 7 site (except migrate and table wizard, not that they don't fit the bill).

**[UPDATE]** - I am currently investigating [nate's approach](http://quicksketch.org/node/5739) when he migrated his site from drupal 5 to 7. It might work for me; I will update.

Comment: What type of content do you need to migrate. Do you have special nodes (like UC products webforms etc.) what type of ratings do you use?

Comment: I have standard five content types with some standard fields like thumbnail image, link field etc previous site was using fivestar, I might use the same .. I am not really worried about rating. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach you are looking at is good. You may need to reconsider your requirements slightly.

- Move content but not upgrade.
- Move some content which is provided by modules (which need to be upgraded).
- Move content which is provided by modules but not the modules themselves.
- Not use Migrate or table wizard.
- Do so in the best way.
- Do so in the quickest way.

I think many of these requirements are mutually exclusive.

The best approach I can see, is to clone your existing site. Turn off everything you don't want in the D7 site. Then consider your upgrade options.

A Drupal install is a complex interaction of code configuration and content. it is difficult to completely consider one without the others.

*update*

You could look at [migrate Drupal 2 Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) for migrating your content.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of success with the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. The Economist.com used migrate to go from their custom CMS to Drupal 6 [Economist.com data migration using migrate](http://drupal.org/node/915102). You setup classes inside of migrate to make lookup so when the data comes over, it does not loose any of its relationship (or makes new relationships based on Drupal architecture). Just my two cents to see if it helps you along.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with customizing nate's custom import modules and it works great except for couple of issues I am facing with a different module. I hope I will resolve it and as expected that solution was quicker and had less clutter as my migration needs were simple. Hopefully I can post back a more general version of that module removing my business logic out of it as it could be really useful in some cases.